# improve robots regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have made the following regexp for extracting robots links:

```
re.compile(r"/\S+(?:\/+)")
```

And i get the following result:

```
/includes/
/modules/
/search/
/?q=user/password/
/?q=user/register/
/node/add/
/logout/
/?q=admin/
/themes/
/?q=node/add/
/admin/
/?q=comment/reply/
/misc/
//example.com/
//example.com/site/
/profiles/
//www.robotstxt.org/wc/
/?q=search/
/user/password/
/?q=logout/
/comment/reply/
/?q=filter/tips/
/?q=user/login/
/user/register/
/user/login/
/scripts/
/filter/tips/
//www.sxw.org.uk/computing/robots/
```

How can i exclude the links that has two slashes like:

```
 //www.sxw.org.uk/computing/robots/
 //www.robotstxt.org/wc/
 //example.com/
 //example.com/site/
```

Any ideas ??

Comment: The backslash before the slash is not needed so can be deleted: `r"/\S+(?:/+)"` Also the non-capturing brackets (`?:`) are not needed, so your regular expression can be simplified to: `r"/\S+/+"` . As the `\S+` captures also slashes the `+` after the last slash is of no use. So we get `r"/\S+/"` . Now we have got a regular expression with the same result as the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest just add an `if` condition:

```
 if not line.startswith(r'//'):
     #then do something here
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the strings to be matches occur on each line as in the sample we can anchor the regex and use negative lookahead

```
^(?!//)/\S+(?:\/+)
```

Be sure to set the regex modifier that makes ^ match the beginning of a line.

My Python is rusty but this should do it

```
for match in re.finditer(r"(?m)^(?!//)/\S+(?:/+)", subject):
    # match start: match.start()
    # match end (exclusive): match.end()
    # matched text: match.group()
```